# echo {$var1..$var2} is not working in shell

Tags: shell

If I execute below command, it will work fine:

```
$ echo BL{1..10};
BL1 BL2 BL3 BL4 BL5 BL6 BL7 BL8 BL9 BL10
```

But if assign 1 and 10 to a variable it won't work:

```
$ a=1;
$ b=10;
$ echo BL{$a..$b}
BL{1..10}
```

here how can I get output like `"BL1 BL2 BL3 BL4 BL5 BL6 BL7 BL8 BL9 BL10"`

Could any of you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Br,
Ranjith

Comment: *"echo {$var1..$var2} is not working in shell"* Any particular shell? bash? csh? sh?

Comment: If you use Bash, it does brace expansion before variable expansion, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html. You can use `seq` command: `seq -f "BL%g" -s ' ' -t '\n' $a $b`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks fir the information. It worked fine.